# What's the proper way to use the callback function event.currentTarget?

Tags: jquery

So I'm trying to get an image too zoom in on `mouseenter` and reset back to normal on `mouseleave`. I tried using `event.currentTarget` to make only one image at a time zoom in and out rather than all of them. Now the issue: my code isn't working, it says there's a syntax error? I've looked at it about 20 times and I don't see where? Did I do something wrong or is my code incorrect? Please let me know if there's a way to simplify this or fix my current code.

```
$('.product-photo').on('mouseenter', (event) => {
    $(event.currentTarget).addClass('photo-active')
  }).on('mouseleave', event => {
    $(event.currentTarget).removeClass('photo-active')
  })
```

CSS code for .photo-active

```
.photo-active {
    background-size: 30.8em 16.5em;
    transition: 0.2s; }
```

Comment: You say "it says there's a syntax error": Problem solution is much easier if you include the error message in the question. Hitting F12 in the browser shows you the developer tools. Error messages are shown in the console tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your script:

It should read `function (event) { ...` instead of `(event) => {`.

I have put a working version on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rasenderhase/wyzkmpph/4/

You may do this without JavaScript:

```
.product-photo:hover {
  background-size: 30.8em 16.5em;
}
```

Comment: works perfectly. I had no idea, thanks for clarifying

Comment: No worries. Try the non-JavaScript solution I have added. You may omit all JavaScript code. Just replace `.photo-active` in your css by `.product-photo:hover` 

Comment: This version is also very funny: https://jsfiddle.net/rasenderhase/wyzkmpph/5/ 

Comment: oh you're right! I'll have to try that out and see how it works. thanks a lot